# adding jQuery transition to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an onclick function which removes a display:none style on an HTML div.

```js
function myFunctionUnder18() {
  document.getElementById("myAgeMessage").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="age" onclick="myFunctionUnder18()" >
<div style="display: none;" id="myAgeMessage"><p>Sorry. You need to be at least 18 years of age.</p></div>
```

Is there a way to add a jQuery effect to function so that the message displays smoothly?

Comment: Yes, by reading into the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the ***duration*** in milliseconds to [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Where ***duration*** is

> A string or number determining how long the animation will run.

```js
function myFunctionUnder18() {
  $("#myAgeMessage").show(1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="age" onclick="myFunctionUnder18()" >
<div style="display: none;" id="myAgeMessage"><p>Sorry. You need to be at least 18 years of age.</p></div>
```

You can also use [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/):

```js
function myFunctionUnder18() {
  $("#myAgeMessage").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="age" onclick="myFunctionUnder18()" >
<div style="display: none;" id="myAgeMessage"><p>Sorry. You need to be at least 18 years of age.</p></div>
```